# How to get Electron app to connect to NeDB

Tags: reactjs, electron, nedb

I am  building an Electron app using React.js. I am attempting to use NeDB as the recommended DB for Electron. However, I cannot get the app to connect to the database.

When I move things around to troubleshoot or attempt to use an IPC I often get this error:

```
TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function (anonymous function)node_modules/electron/index.js:6
```

Link to repository: https://github.com/hcuffy/react-grade

How can I get connect to NeDB from my Electron app?

---

### **Update**

- I got the DB to be created and connected by placing the DB connection in the main process.
- Attempting to access the DB from the renderer process generates the error above.
  Remote is not accessing the db in main.

Comment: Check this http://www.riptutorial.com/electron/example/32649/connecting-electron-app-with-nedb

Comment: @Akram the DB is create but I cannot interact with it from the renderer procss